# Missing required parameter for [Route: user.destroy]

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Tengo una función en javascript para eliminar un registro, ya tengo el id, pero al mandarlo en la ruta por ajax al controlador de estilo resource (destroy) de Laravel 8, no envía dicha solicitud porque creo que la variable con el id no la envía y me salta el siguiente error.

**Error el cual es porque no se envia el id como ruta lo cual solicita la funcion destroy del controlador en laravel**

```
Missing required parameter for [Route: user.destroy] [URI: admin/user/{user}] [Missing parameter: user]. (View: C:\wamp64\www\david_paucar\resources\views\backend\user.blade.php)
```

**¿Cómo puedo mandar correctamente la variable de id ya que la ruta está con sintaxis laravel, o cómo puedo mandarla correctamente?**

```
/* DELETE */
    $(document).on('click', '#deleteInfo', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let deleteInfoId = $('#deleteInfo').prop('value');

        $.ajax({
            url    : '{{route('user.destroy')}}' + '/' + deleteInfoId,
            method : 'DELETE',
            data   : {
                id    : deleteInfoId,
                _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

**Controlador estilo resource**

Este es el controlador el cual espera la siguiente ruta para que funcione

```
public function destroy($id) {
        ddd($id);
        DB::table('user_information')->where('id', '=', $id)->delete();
    }
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estoy en archivo .blade y al final de él estoy escribiendo código javascript, pero en la ruta ocupo sintaxis blade pero el id de javascript no sé como concatenarlo para que se envíe correctamente y mi ruta es de tipo resource.

Comment: Nada compa, sigo teniendo el mismo error 

Comment: Si @BetaM me funcionó la solución que compartiste, pero seguiré buscando si hay alguna forma más sencilla.